# What are the localizations of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ at prime ideals in general?

Tags: commutative-algebra

(This self-answer post was extracted from an answer I posted in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/685844/326036); see [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36214/326036).)

Is there a general rule for computing the localization of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ at a prime ideal?

This computation is useful, for example, in coming up with [counterexamples that localization is a local property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146958/326036), providing examples of [localizing at a submonoid containing zero divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/847982/326036), and in general when seeing examples of localizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$

The prime ideals of $\Z/n\Z$ are of the form $(p) = p\Z/n\Z$ where $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$.
In general, we have:
$$(\Z/n\Z)_{(p)} \cong \Z/p^{\mathrm{ord}_p(n)}\Z$$
where $\mathrm{ord}_p(n)$ denotes the multiplicity of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$.

We can see this in two steps.
Let $S$ be the multiplicatively closed set $\Z/n\Z \setminus (p)$.
Elements of this localization are of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a, b \in \Z$ and $p \nmid b$ (by abuse of notation we use integers to denote the corresponding image in $\Z/n\Z$).
Let $m = \mathrm{ord}_p(n)$.
Then:

1. We can rewrite any of these fractions as a fraction with denominator $1$, as $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ab^*}{1}$ where $b^*$ denotes a multiplicative inverse of $b$ modulo $p^m$ (which exists because $b$ is coprime to $p^m$). Indeed, $a\cdot 1 - (ab^*)\cdot b \equiv 0 \mod p^m$ so we can multiply it by the integer $\frac{n}{p^m}$, which is in $S$ by definition of $m$, to get $0$ in $\Z/n\Z$.
2. Fractions with equal denominator (which we can now assume is 1) are equal iff their numerators are congruent modulo $p^m$. Indeed, $\frac{a}{1} = \frac{a'}{1}$ iff there exists an integer $k$ coprime to $p$ such that $k(a - a') \equiv 0 \mod n$. By unique factorization, this happens iff $a \equiv a' \mod p^m$.

Therefore the localization is a ring with the $p^m$ elements $\frac01,\frac{1}{1}$, $\frac{2}{1}, \ldots, \frac{p^m-1}{1}$, and its additive group is cyclic, so it must be isomorphic to $\Z/p^m\Z$.

---

So, for example:

- $(\Z/6\Z)_{(3)} \cong \Z/3\Z$
- $(\Z/6\Z)_{(2)} \cong \Z/2\Z$
- $(\Z/12\Z)_{(2)} \cong \Z/4\Z$
- For any composite squarefree $n$, all the localizations of $\Z/n\Z$ at primes will be fields of a prime number of elements, so it constitutes an example of a non-domain which is locally everywhere a domain.